# Conditional type denies assigning

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I am trying to assign `null` if the client not logged in, `ClientUser` if the client logged in.
(Type `ClientUser` is not equal to `null`, yes)

I tried this:

```js
export class Client<Ready extends boolean = boolean> extends EventEmitter {
    loggedin: boolean = false;
    user: Ready extends true ? CliendtUser : Ready extends false ? null : never = null;
    isReady(): this is Client<true> {
        return this.loggedin === true;
    }
```

```
src/Client.ts(87,5): error TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Ready extends true ? ClientUser : Ready extends false ? null : never'.
```

How can I assign null without the error?

Comment: So you are saying that when `Ready` is `true`, the type of `user` is `CliendtUser`? But you want to assign `null` anyway even if `Ready` is `true`?

Comment: Yes, want to assign `ClientUser` if `Ready` is `true`

Comment: Looking at your code you are extending boolean for this interface, why not assign `false` instead of `null`?

Comment: you mean `user: Ready extends true ? ClientUser : Ready`?